# OrmLite in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, ormlite

I'm trying to add ormLite to my project. I used these tutorial:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=beb-n2yq0kM

But I can't create the configFile, because I everytime get these error:

```
Could not find raw directory, which is typically in the rew directory
```

I found this solution:

[Ormlite DatabaseConfigUtil.java generating raw empty file and database fields are not added](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17319349/ormlite-databaseconfigutil-java-generating-raw-empty-file-and-database-fields-ar)

But if I'm using these method, he creates a extra res folder in project/app and in this the raw folder with my config. But I think, that he should use project/app/src/main/res.

But if I'm setting the whole path, I just get the same error.

Anybody have a idea? Thanks for help :)